# How to force Eclipse to ask for default workspace?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, workspace

I noticed that after installing cdt, Eclipse always loads the default workspace. The workspace listed in the `config.ini` in `osgi.instance.area.default`. Eclipse does not ask which workspace to open regardless if `Prompt for workspace on startup` is set or not.

How do I force Eclipse to ask which workspace to load on startup?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I had the same problem with indigo on linux 3.0 X86_64:
After runnning `eclipse -clean` everything went back to normal.

Thanks to some comment on the eclipse issue:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=134412

Comment: I will try once I get to that problematic eclipse

Comment: For OSX, I had to type: `$ PATH_TO_ECLIPSE/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse -clean` and it worked.

Comment: @Amit: That did not work for me when I had the problem with my workspace. The tick would just be ignored by eclipse...

Comment: Now two cases may happen if 1. you didn't click the eclipse button or 2. If u installed eclipse as root and now u are trying to alter its properties in non root instance...

Comment: start eclipse, Window->Preference->  type "workspace" in the search box. click workspaces then tick the box with "promote workspaces when start up"

Comment: Thanks!  I needed to -clean -- after searching I found that this indeed just cleans certain _caches_ out, so it's totally safe.

Comment: This worked for me on a Windows installation. Eclipse stopped asking for the workspace, despite the preference, after eclipse crashed. Might be worth doing a clean after any crash as other, less visible settings may be altered or corrupt somehow.

Comment: -clean doesn't work for me on Mac. The problem started after I installed EGit, ADT and ADT Translation Manager.

Comment: This still happens on the last eclipse Mars. The command solved it, thanks!

Comment: @IvanRF: what command solved it for you? Are you referring to -clean? I have an RCP app built on Luna, and nothing I do makes the workspace location prompt appear on startup.

Comment: @MidnightJava Yes, I used `eclipse -clean`, the prompt was restored and I could set my default workspace.

Answer (score 114):

It works for me if I tick the box **Prompt for workspace on startup**, which you can find in
**Window → Preferences → General → Startup and Shutdown → Workspaces**.

Comment: I have installed Eclipse Classic with C/C++ and CDT plugins

Comment: And that switch works for you? I have Eclipse Indigo with CDT and it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, it does indeed. Perhaps you should switch also to 'Classic'. Before that I used the Eclipse PHP and I had some update problems with that. For me, Eclipse Classic works smoother ...

Comment: Oh, may be that is a bug. I have Eclipse for Java EE.

Comment: hey andreas i have eclipse galalio so i haven't any options like "Prompt for workspace on startup". so what can i do for this eclipse?

Answer (score 35):

Inside the `configuration/.settings` folder of your Eclipse installation, there is a file called `org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs`. Open this file in a text editor and change the property `SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG` from `false` to `true`.

Tested with Eclipse 3.7 on Windows.

Comment: I am having this problem (under Linux) and the property is already set to true.

Comment: I tried this on Ubuntu 11.10/Eclipse 3.7 and it worked. What version(s) are you using?

Comment: At the time I was using Fedora 14 (I don't remember which version of Eclipse, sorry). I have since switched to Ubuntu and everything works nicely.

Comment: It is true but doesn't help. (Ubuntu 12.04, Eclipse Juno)

Comment: This is what worked for me.  I had switched to a workspace that made Eclipse hang.  I couldn't get to “Prompt for workspace at startup” therefore.

Comment: This worked for me in an environment where eclipse hung due to a corrupt workspace and I needed the prompt to choose another workspace, the command line arguments provided in the thread had no effect. (Eclipse Version: 3.7.2 x64-bit, Windows 7)

Comment: This solution still works with Eclipse Mars 2. Thanks !

Answer (score 27):

Using Eclipse Indigo this is how I did it:

Window → Preferences → Startup and Shutdown → Workspaces

Check the box at the top of the window that says "Prompt for workspace on startup"

Comment: Yes, IF you can start Eclipse to begin with. If not, see alternate solutions of course.

Answer (score 4):

The “Prompt for workspace at startup” checkbox did not working.
You can setting default workspace, Look for the folder named “configuration” in the Eclipse installation directory, and open up the “config.ini” file.
You’ll edit the "osgi.instance.area.default" to supply your desired default workspace.

Answer (score 4):

*Version: Eclipse CIndigo Service Release 2*

1. File > Switch Workspace > Other...
2. In the textbox, write the path in the Workspace  or **Browse**

It automatically sets the default Workspace during exit.

Answer (score 3):

I followed the thread and tired all things but didn't work. Finally I saw that my eclipse shortcut target is like below

```
C:\Eclipse_3.6\eclipse\eclipse.exe -clean -data "C:\workplace" ...
```

I simply removed -data option and it worked. Now I got popup to choose workspace at startup.

cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Starting eclipse with `eclipse -clean` did wonders for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue (in Eclipse Juno), but I just wanted to change the default workspace to the one I'm using

There's a setting in `ECLIPSE_DIRECTORY/configuration/config.ini` that is causing a specific workspace to be loaded without prompting for a workspace. If you just want to change the default workspace, you can just modify the value or add it if it doesn't exist:

```
osgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/some_workspace
```

or

```
osgi.instance.area.default=/some/absolute/path/some_workspace
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Window → Preferences → General → Startup and Shutdown → Workspaces** (or **Eclipse → Preferences → ...** on macOS)

Check the checkbox **Prompt for workspace on startup**

Then at startup Eclipse will ask for workspace selection.

Comment: Did you check it what I have mentioned.

Comment: I have written about this check box in the question. It doesn't help neither it is switched on nor off.

Comment: In Window - Preferances - Select Restore Defaluts and Apply buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that I am having the same issue. I am also using Eclipse classic with CDT. The funny thing is that it only started happening earlier this evening. Before then, I was always prompted for the workspace. Checking **Prompt for workspace on startup** has no effect. I am not launching eclipse using a startup script, so the `-data` flag is not set on launch. I have removed the line `osgi.instance.area.default` from the `configuration/config.ini` file, but that had no effect.

A few strange quirks that are incidental to this problem: If I delete the `workspace` workspace it creates it again upon launch. However, when I switch to one of my "real" workspaces I notice that the `workspace` workspace is not listed as an option to be switched to.

As would be expected, reinstalling Eclipse resolves the issue. But it would be nicer to find a way to fix the problem without resorting to that.

Comment: reinstalling helps? heh, would probably try to install cdt on fresh eclipse copy, but in that case this problem should be with other plugins

Comment: I was having the problem and I never installed the CDT, so I think installing the CDT is a red-herring. As with Jim Kaiser, none of the other solutions fixed my problem. But reinstalling a fresh Eclipse (J-EE in my case) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Under Aptana 3.2.2, in `\configuration\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs`, edit:

```
RECENT_WORKSPACES=I\:\\PDT\\workspace
```

It will check the recent workspace, so just set it to what you want. I do it for running off an external drive.

Comment: This is the fix I was looking for.  I propose this as the best low-level answer, especially if Eclipse won't start due to corruption.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Eclipse, and calling `eclipse -clean` did not solve the problem.

In the end I figured out that within the installation folder of Eclipse there is a script called `eclipse`. This script does some setting of environment variables and then calls `eclipse.bin`. The call for `eclipse.bin` contained the this command-line switch:

```
-data ~/.eclipse
```

When I removed that switch from start-up script, I got the workspace selection as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Editing the `config.ini` file with

```
osgi.instance.area.default=\D:\\Projects\\Eclipse Workspace\\
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I first tried the `-clean` option, but that didn't solve the problem. Then I added the `-data` option with the correct path to the workspace, which worked.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by adding the `-showLocation` flag to `eclipse.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to pay attention to howw Eclipse is launched. I ever pinned Eclipse by rigk-click on the excutable and pinning it to taskbar. In this way, the Eclipse is launched to use settings under c:\User\public\public Documents\eclipse" which is not very desirable.

However, if you pin it by creating a short-cut, then it will launch to use settings in the folder of Eclipse installation.  Then everything makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If your Eclipse is auto-closing at startup you can

- Open the properties of your shortcut and add `-clean` at the end of the path,
- Or, in a command prompt, run `C:\PATH_TO_YOUR_ECLIPSE\eclipse -clean` like mentioned in the comments and other answers

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to create a shortcut to eclipse.exe with the `-data` command line option. This way you can create a **separate shortcut to each workspace** you use, and avoid unnecessary dialogs and mouse clicks.

Windows: Just create an Eclipse shortcut on your desktop, then right-click to open `Properties` and under `Shortcut` set something like this as `Target`: `C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -data C:\Path\to\your\workspace1`. This will launch Eclipse and automatically open `workspace1`.

Repeat the steps for all the workspaces you use often.