# FDT Hangs On Startup

Tags: eclipse, fdt

I have ben unable to start FDT. It keeps at the loading
screen. I have already uninstall and reinstall FDT and still cant open it.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to say what might be happening. It sounds like it's related to your workspace not being accessed properly.

Here are some things to try:

- Try deleting your workspace or choose a different one on startup. (Most likely will fix it)
- Run '[eclipse -clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058782/how-to-force-eclipse-to-ask-for-default-workspace)' argument.
- If that doesn't work, try deleting your 'FDT' folder on your hard disk at: Home>Library>Application Support> FDT