# Why does NOT my Eclipse ask for workspace on startup?

Tags: eclipse, workspace

In my Eclipse:

Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown -> Workspaces:

And the "Prompt for workspace on startup" is checked, but anytime I start Eclipse, it does NOT ask for workspace to open.

Why is that? Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058782/how-to-force-eclipse-to-ask-for-default-workspace?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058782/how-to-force-eclipse-to-ask-for-default-workspace?

Comment: yes, someone write this: "It works for me if I tick the box 'Prompt for workspace on startup', which you find in Window > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown > Workspaces." but it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try starting Eclipse with `eclipse.exe -clean`. You can also manually edit Eclipse files, but better use the supported run argument. As I already commented - this is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058782/how-to-force-eclipse-to-ask-for-default-workspace), but you seem to have skipped it and went straight for the second answer :-)

Comment: Oh thanks! Yeh, I skipped it, because I thought the setting up in preferences should be enough :-) thank you!

Comment: Notably the documentation about the `osgi.clean` (i.e. `-clean`) switch is not pointing that out: 
_if set to "true", any cached data used by the OSGi framework and eclipse runtime will be wiped clean. This will clean the caches used to store bundle dependency resolution and eclipse extension registry data. Using this option will force eclipse to reinitialize these caches._

Answer (score 1):

1/ Check the value of -startup in eclipse.ini.
   IF - startup you find

-startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcherXXXXXX.jar

it's OK

if you find other values comment them

2/ you go to ( in eclipse ): preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown  > workspaces and then you check ( prompt for workspace on startup )

3/ you run you eclipse with eclipse.exe -clean