# Aptana won't open

Tags: aptana, aptana3

I've installed new 3.6.0 version of the Aptana few weeks ago and everything worked well.
Yesterday I tried to open it and it won't start. After clicking on start icon loading icon shows for few seconds and nothing happens.

I was looking for a error log but there is no anything. I re-installed it last night and everything worked well. Today, after PC restart again the same problem.

I restarted it few times and it worked for few days and again the same. 
Now I found log in configuration/derby.log and it says:

```
    2014-08-24 17:26:46.960 GMT Thread[main,6,main] Cleanup action starting
java.sql.SQLException: Database 'aptanaDB' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleDBNotFound(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.aptana.usage.internal.AptanaDB.shutdown(AptanaDB.java:160)
    at com.aptana.usage.UsagePlugin.stop(UsagePlugin.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1206)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:692)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:200)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Database 'aptanaDB' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    ... 37 more
============= begin nested exception, level (1) ===========
java.sql.SQLException: Database 'aptanaDB' not found.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.newEmbedSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.newSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleDBNotFound(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection30.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection40.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.Driver40.getNewEmbedConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.InternalDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.AutoloadedDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.aptana.usage.internal.AptanaDB.shutdown(AptanaDB.java:160)
    at com.aptana.usage.UsagePlugin.stop(UsagePlugin.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1206)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:692)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:200)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
============= end nested exception, level (1) ===========
Cleanup action completed
```

Comment: Closevoter: Questions about development tools, including IDEs, are *expressly on-topic*.

Answer (score 0):

According to [APSTUD-3610](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3610) this is a known issue but is probably not the source of your problem.

If you're opening a workspace by default, have you checked the .metadata/.log in the project to see what is being logged by Aptana? You can try to start Aptana 'clean': `AptanaStudio3 -clean` to see if this helps. See: [How to force Eclipse to ask for default workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058782/how-to-force-eclipse-to-ask-for-default-workspace)

This discussion may also be helpful: [How to recover corrupted Eclipse workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950476/how-to-recover-corrupted-eclipse-workspace)