# Why Eclipse Kepler opens default workspace on startup regardless of the prompt preference?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

On start up, Eclipse Kepler always opens the welcome information with **a default blank workspace**. Eclipse cannot restore the workspace when it exists. Also, **it no longer ask** for workspace on startup **regardless if the prompt preference is chenked**.

So everytime I have to manually open the default workspace by clicking on *"File"-->"Switch Workspace"* and chosing my workspace. This is annoying.

I think I have made the correct settings. On *"Preferences"-->"General"-->"Startup and Shutdown"-->"Workspace"*, I enable the option "Prompt for workspace on startup". But it never worked.

Accroding to another question[How to force Eclipse to ask for default workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058782/how-to-force-eclipse-to-ask-for-default-workspace), **I tried the "-clean" parameter**. However it is still no use.

Is it a bug for Eclipse Kepler or I have made a wrong setting? Any Advice to fix the problem? Thanks ahead.

#### More informations are as follows:

- OS: Windows 8.1 x86 Edition: Eclipse Kepler Standard Edition Service
  Release 2
- Plugins: ADT Plugins only
- Install path: D:\Program Files\Eclipse
- Parameters: No parameters used to launch Eclipse.exe, just like "D:\Program Files\Eclipse\e

clipse.exe"

#### Discussions similar to this problems:

- [Bug 134412 - [WorkbenchLauncher] No workspace prompt on startup](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=134412)
- [Bug 409552 - [WorkbenchLauncher] Workspace prompt on startup in eclipse is not working](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=409552)

Comment: Did you fiddle with the eclipse.ini file?

Comment: I have never changed this file manually.

Comment: There is [a similar discussion on the Eclipse forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/490088/1188611/#msg_1188611) which may be helpful to understand the issue.

Comment: Could it be, that Eclipse isn't able to write its preference file, because of windows User Access Control?

Comment: I noticed this possibility that UAC may causes this issue. But when I launch the Eclipse Kepler by Administrator, it still opened the default blank workspace.

Comment: A better UAC test is to completely turn off this feature, and/or move Eclipse to a directory, that is not a child directory of /programs/ or /users/ and /windows/

Answer (score 0):

Until now, there is several ways to try:

1. Launch the Eclipse.exe by adding a `-clean` parameter. According to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058782/how-to-force-eclipse-to-ask-for-default-workspace).
2. Launch the Eclipse.exe by adding a `-data <work space>` parameter. According to [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/490088/1244743/#msg_1244743).
3. Delete the `eclipse.ini` file. According to [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/490088/1404658/#msg_1404658).

As for me, **the second way is a workaround** although I still don't know the reason. The first is popular on the web but not working for me, while the third way is not recommended by myself.

Futher discussions or answers are welcomed.