# How to change eclipse shortcut settings

Tags: eclipse, windows

I am using eclipse kepler on window 7, now my eclipse shortcut in start menu have some default setting which I can see by right click --> properties. [image]

The setting in target are

```
"C:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipse.exe" -configuration "C:\Users\Public\Documents\eclipse\configuration" -data "C:\Users\Public\Documents\eclipse\workspace" -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\/bin/javaw"
```

which are enabling eclipse to run in default workspace. I tried to change the setting by removing the -data "path" parameter and adding -clean to it, but whenever I am restarting my computer they are resetting back to the old value making me change them again. I should mentioned that the eclipse is corporate version of eclipse. Does anyone know how can I permanently change these setting so that eclipse will ask me for choosing the workspace.

Comment: Maybe 2nd Answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058782/how-to-force-eclipse-to-ask-for-default-workspace might help you

Comment: @Vihar Thanks for looking but that options is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Window->Preferences in Eclipse, filter on workspace and under General>Startup and Shutdown>Workspaces set to "Prompt for workspace on startup" to true (checked).

You could also try opening C:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs and setting 
SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=true

Comment: honestly I have tried both and they are set as specified but still I am facing the mentioned issue

Comment: Hmm. Can you make your own short cut and just use the settings you like? Then add that to the start menu or desktop?